# Using a delimiter to search for multiple terms in a like terms

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I had encountered this problem yesterday and thought I had solved it but I was wrong. For the purpose of this script, I'll need the variables to be in a string with a delimiter (this is because end users will search for terms in account titles).

Say for instance the end users wanted to search for when 'Water' or 'Food' are contained within a title. They need not be in the same title. The results could return 'Water of the world' and 'Food for thought'.

I understand that I could easily write this using a couple of AND and OR statements

```
 SELECT ...
 FROM ...
 WHERE 1=1
 and (rpt_title LIKE '%Food%' 
 or rpt_title LIKE '%Water%')
```

The variable will be taking just one parameter, but as a string. (i.e = 'Food | Water'). I already have a function that will take a character delimited string and turn it into multiple variables. I do not think this is the solution. I think I'd need to use substring and charindex to locate the delimiter ( a | in this case, because it's most likely not in a title) and then turn it into an OR statement.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

EDIT: The end result would be the ability to enter in a variable 
     (e.g - rpt_title LIKE '%'+@title+'%')

Comment: Your are trying to mimic full text search, so you might as well use that database functionality . . . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571(v=sql.105).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think splitting would be such a bad idea. You can create a relatively efficient inline TVF and join against that, e.g. assuming you have a Numbers table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN
   (
       SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
         CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
       FROM dbo.Numbers
       WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
         AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
   );
GO
```

(For the absolute most efficient approaches, e.g. CLR, see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Now you can say:

```
SELECT t.rpt_title
  FROM dbo.table_name AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers(@Input, '|') AS x
  ON t.rpt_title LIKE '%' + x.Item + '%'
  GROUP BY t.rpt_title;
```

Another idea is to not use a list like `foo|bar|splunge` in the first place, but rather use TVPs. First create a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TitleMatches
(
  Pattern NVARCHAR(64)
);
GO
```

Then a stored procedure that uses it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Whatever
  @matches dbo.TitleMatches READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.rpt_title
    FROM dbo.table_name AS t
    INNER JOIN @matches AS m
    ON t.rpt_title LIKE '%' + m.Pattern + '%'
    GROUP BY t.rpt_title;
END
GO
```

Then you just need to pass in your DataTable or whatever structure holds your list of potential matches, e.g. in C# this might look like:

```cs
DataTable DataTableName = new DataTable();

// ... populate data table here

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Whatever", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvp = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matches", DataTableName);
tvp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

// ... execute, consume results, etc.
```

(More details on this at http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)

Comment: As with the other answer, I think this may need a `SELECT DISTINCT` in case a title matches more than one keyword.

Comment: @EdGibbs I've added a `GROUP BY` (which will perform no worse than `DISTINCT` but can perform better in some cases), but this all depends on whether they want to analyze the results for *each* keyword independently. I might want to know, for example, that a title matched both food *and* water. I might even want to rank them based on *which* keyword(s) they matched.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm deleting mine since it's contained on your first part of the answer.

Comment: Extremely detailed, I actually will attempt to learn how you've constructed this before just plopping it into my query!! Also @Aaron. I took am from RI -- small world.

Comment: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: @AaronBertrand , in your first example where you create a function that takes my Item and my delimiter, is it possible to pass in a multi character delimiter? say for instance I wanted to have a delimiter that was a space | space, as opposed to just a | ... first is it possible? secondly, where in the function would I change that so it can take multiple characters?

Comment: @user2191477 Yes, it is possible. The function will already take any Unicode delimiter <= 255 characters, but the body was foolishly written assuming it would always be 1. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a little dirty, but it worked. Forgive me, I have not done TSQL in some time.

```
DECLARE @delim CHAR, @search NVARCHAR(100)
set @delim = '|'
set @search = 'world|food'

DECLARE @tblSearch TABLE(
string NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @tmpStr NVARCHAR(100)
WHILE (@search <> '')
BEGIN
    IF (CHARINDEX(@delim, @search) = 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblSearch(string) VALUES('%' + @search + '%')
            SET @search = ''
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblSearch(string)
            SELECT '%' + SUBSTRING(@search, 0, CHARINDEX(@delim, @search)) + '%'
            SET @search = SUBSTRING(@search, CHARINDEX(@delim, @search) + 1, LEN(@search))
        END
END

SELECT ...
FROM ... as m
INNER JOIN @tblSearch as s ON m.rpt_title like s.string
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use dynamic tsql as shown below. Unfortunately I've read many times that it's not efficient to use because it can't be precompiled by the server and has to be optimized at runtime every time it runs, which is slower than the way you're doing it. However, I think this should accomplish what you're asking for.
To run this, call it with
proc_DelimitedQuery 'aaa|bbb|etc'

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_DelimitedQuery]

@delimitedString varchar(100)
as

DECLARE @delimiter int
declare @pos int
DECLARE @item varchar(500)
Declare @criteria varchar(5000)

set @criteria = '(rpt_title like ''%'

set @pos=1

--find the first delimiter
SET @delimiter = CHARINDEX('|', @delimitedString, @pos)

WHILE @delimiter<>0
BEGIN
    set @item=substring(@delimitedString, @pos, @delimiter-@pos)
    set @criteria = @criteria + @item + '%'' or rpt_title like ''%'

    --Find the next delimiter
    set @pos=@delimiter+1

    if charindex('|', @delimitedString, @pos)=0
    begin

        set @pos=@delimiter+1
        set @item=substring(@delimitedString, @pos, datalength(@delimitedString)-@delimiter)
        set @criteria = @criteria + @item + '%'')'      
        set @delimiter=0
    end
    else
    begin
        set @delimiter=charindex('|', @delimitedString, @pos)
    end


END

declare @sql varchar(500)
set @sql='select * from MyTable where 1=1 and ' + @criteria

    --change the next line to select @sql if you want to examine the sql statement
EXECUTE(@sql)
GO
```